# Slow MySQL query with AS and subquery

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, subquery

I have a problem with this slow query that runs for 10+ seconds:

```
SELECT DISTINCT siteid,
                storyid,
                added,
                title,
                subscore1,
                subscore2,
                subscore3,
                ( 1 * subscore1 + 0.8 * subscore2 + 0.1 * subscore3 ) AS score
FROM   articles
WHERE  added > '2011-10-23 09:10:19'
       AND ( articles.feedid IN (SELECT userfeeds.siteid
                                 FROM   userfeeds
                                 WHERE  userfeeds.userid = '1234')
              OR ( articles.title REGEXP '[[:<:]]keyword1[[:>:]]' = 1
                    OR articles.title REGEXP '[[:<:]]keyword2[[:>:]]' = 1 ) )
ORDER  BY score DESC
LIMIT  0, 25
```

This outputs a list of stories based on the sites that a user added to his account. The ranking is determined by score, which is made up out of the subscore columns.

The query uses filesort and uses indices on PRIMARY and feedid.
Results of an EXPLAIN:

```
1   PRIMARY articles    
range   
PRIMARY,added,storyid   
PRIMARY  729263 rows    
Using where; Using filesort

2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  
userfeeds   
index_subquery  storyid,userid,siteid_storyid   
siteid  func    
1 row   
Using where
```

Any suggestions to improve this query? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the calculation logic to the client and only load fields from the database. This makes your query and the calculation itself faster. It's not a good style to do such things in SQL code.
And also is the regex very slow, maybe another searching mode like 'LIKE' is faster.

Comment: Thanks. I compared regex and LIKE, but no significant gains there. The results are many thousands of stories, so I'm not sure I should load these all in PHP and then start ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `EXPLAIN`, it doesn't appear your query is utilizing any index (thus the filesort). This is being caused by the sort on the calculated column (`score`).

Another barrier is the size of the table (729263 rows). You don't want to create an index that is too wide as it will take much more space and impact performance of your CUD operations. What we want to do is target the columns that are being selected, however, in this situation we can't since it's a calculated column. You can try creating a `VIEW` or either remove the sort or do it at the application layer.